# How to get the coefficients of determination (R Squared) from factor loadings in FAVAR?

Tags: time-series, estimation, factor-analysis, vector-autoregression

I estimated a FAVAR (Factor Augmented VAR) model for forecasting purposes. The FAVAR gave a very low RMSE value compared to VAR. However, I am unable to interpret the factors through factor loadings. Usually researches incorporate coefficient of determination (R squared) to interpret the factors. But, how to get the R squared values by using factor loadings.
Given below is a snapshot of the factor loadings of the fitted model:

[image]

Very low factor loadings might be since the series are log differenced.